# details of Android application components destruction and recreation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

Could someone push me in the direction of some concrete, trustworthy (and preferably concise) information on the following:

1. The order in which components are destroyed and (where applicable)recreated by the system
   (Fragment, Activity, Activity's Threads/AsyncTasks/Timers,
   static data(when are classes unloaded?), Threads/AsyncTasks/Timers in other classes, host
   TabActivity, ActivityGroup, bound local Services, Application, process)
   both when the app is in the background, and in the foreground.
   At which points the destruction can stop (what states can be encountered
   upon return to the app - like "everything including the Application object
   destroyed, process alive"?
2. Is it possible (without modifying Android) to programmatically cause the same kind of destruction
   ourselves, so that it is indistinguishable from when the system does it, or is a separate mechanism needed for when we ourselves choose to free memory (triggered by onLowMemory)?
3. Reliable reproduction steps of all scenarios from 1) (would junit.framework do? I haven't investigated that) ?
4. "[If the user leaves a task for a long time, the system clears the task of all activities except the root activity. When the user returns to the task again, only the root activity is restored](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html#Clearing)": is this aside from the process/component lifecycle/destruction, or tied to it?

I have read various sources give pieces of information, often incomplete and misleading, sometimes incorrect.
I admit, I have skimmed over some parts of the documentation, so i may have missed or misunderstood something.

[EDIT] To avoid misunderstandings: What I am asking about is Android destroying components to free memory, *bypassing* Activity.onDestroy.
When I put the app in the background and return later, the one of these sequences will occur:

- onPause, onStop, onRestart, onStart, onResume
- onPause, onStop, Application.onCreate, onCreate(notNull), onStart, onResume

[EDIT2]
Bounty started. Need reliable info on: Activities, Fragments, Application, bound (potentially remote)Services, process.
Partial/full destruction scenarios. See 1st point.

Comment: "What I am asking about is Android destroying components to free memory" -- Android does not destroy components to free memory. It terminates processes to free memory.

Comment: @CommonsWare The wording here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html and here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html, refers to "Activity" rather than "process". It even says "Once your activity is stopped, the system might destroy the instance if it needs to recover system memory. In extreme cases(...) kill your app process" - so, unless that is a case of supremely misleading docs, process killing is "extreme", and individual Activities can be destroyed, too.

Comment: Additionally, I remember the process still being present when I would return to an app and see Activities being recreated. If the process was killed, this no longer happened. This led me to write my answer to point 4.

Comment: The docs are wrong. http://commonsware.com/blog/2011/10/03/activities-not-destroyed-to-free-heap-space.html

Comment: @CommonsWare Finally something semisolid, many thanks. Now if there were only an answer here I could award the bounty to... preferably one that also addressed onStop, and 4th point of the question

Answer (score 2):

This is what my experience, and that of devs I've asked, seems to suggest:

1. - Fragments are not autodestroyed.
   - non-visible Activities on the app's stack can be autodestroyed in any order, and in any number.
   - destroyed Activity's (or any other class's) Threads and statics remain untouched until Application is destroyed.
   - TimerTasks: haven't tested.
   - bound local Services: destroyed somewhere between the destruction of the last binding Activity and of Application.
   - Application is the last thing to go within a process, and "goes" along with all Threads.
   - the process can exist for a long (20+ minutes) time after the destruction of the Application object, unless you have an automatic task killer.
   - Activities under TabActivity or in ActivityGroups are not autodestroyed, but go all at once if the container is destroyed.
     Example: a TabActivity with ActivityGroups under tabs. All Activities live. Another Activity is started, fullscreen. The TabActivity with everything in it is now eligible for destruction by Android, all at once or not at all.
2. *NO*.
   If you destroy an Activity manually, it goes through the entire lifecycle and doesn't pass a Bundle to onCreate when started again.
   Also, onLowmemory is unreliable - even with small allocation steps, it might never be called before OutOfMemoryError is thrown.
3. *NO*.
   Despite the autodestruction/restoration being such a major feature in Android, there isn't any way to test such scenarios.
4. This is probably related *only* to whether the process still exists or not. If it does, Android will attempt to restore the old Activities. If not, it's a clean restart.

The above include some assumptions.
I am still waiting for someone to confirm it and supply some docs (guarantees not dependent on the current implementation of classes).
Please, PLEASE correct me if any of this is wrong.

Edit: The above information may be out of date, it was tested on Android 2.1-2.3

Answer (score 2):

Credit for this goes to [hackbod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/236398/hackbod) for writing it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536988/android-app-out-of-memory-issues-tried-everything-and-still-at-a-loss/7576275#7576275)(read the whole answer), and to [CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/115145/commonsware) for linking in a comment.

In short:  All the [docs](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/stopping.html), rewritten many times, continue to lie to us. They're not misleading, they just give us untrue information. Unless you're using Fragments (dunno if support v4 counts, too), Android frees memory by killing the whole process, or does nothing.

Of course, this does not address everything:

- Point 4 of the question
- Why I frequently saw onCreate(notNull) on pressing Back on an Activity stack with Activities handling all config changes (Android 2.3.7)
- How this relates to the widely accepted belief that onPause is the last call you are certain to get, and onStop may never get called (how, then, can the app go to the background, to be killed?)

We're getting somewhere, though.

Comment: Correction: we're getting nowhere. The above questions remain unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

Well, my friend,
I guess you'll have a lot of trouble in your research. Basically because you're talking about two black boxes: the Dalvik garbage collector and the android heap manager. I would say that you cannot trust that android will follow any order of object destruction. But, you can trust that this lifecycle is going to be followed [Programming Android, 2011]:

Activity Lifecycle:

```
onCreate() - Called after the instance of the activity has been created for the first  time
onRestart() - Called after an activity has been interrupted, just before the onStart();
onStart() - Called when the object activity and their visions become visible to the user;
onResume()-  Called when the object activity and their visions become interactive to the user;
onPause() - Called when a different instance of the activity is going to get visible and the present activity ceases to interact with the user
onStop() - Called when the activity is no longer visible or is not interacting
onDestroy() - Called when an activity instance must be destroyed and it's no longer needed.
```

Fragments have different lifecycles including methods onAttach, onCreateView and onActivityCreated .
But, why do you care about the objects order of destruction? I can't see no reason for you to monitor such events, but if you really need, learn more about the garbage collector.

Comment: 1. That only covers the case of an Activity being shown once.
2. I get requests to build apps with IOS-like navigation - nested tabs with their own backstacks. I don't get to design it. I get to deal with onCreate(notNull) navigating backstacks after returning from a launched video player after 20 minutes, on low memory. Sure, there were no Fragments back when I had the majority of those problems, but that does not change the fact that I MAY have a similar problem again, and my observations line up with neither the docs, nor hackbod's statements contradicting the former.

Comment: Also, you seem to be suggesting that reading about the GC will lead me to a way to monitor the recreation order. I don't think that's true. Would be useful, though, as it would not only tell me WHY some strange scenarios are occurring, but also show (through weeks of testing, sadly) what to be ready for: at which point to initialize connections, in which classes to know that backwards navigation is no longer possible, etc. Being ready for everything, everywhere, adds 2 orders of magnitude to difficulty. See bitmaps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240502

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer but what I would recommend is that you place toast messages in each of these methods. Add in your own `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onResume()`, etc. and inside put a line like this:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "onPause()", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

You cannot directly call these methods, however moving another activity to the top of the stack will of cause these methods on the existing activity to be called. One more thing to keep in mind is that `onCreate()` need not be called every time you start an activity. It really depends on how you start the activity, for example if you send this intent

```
Intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

it will appear call `onNewIntent()` instead if it has already been created.  In summary the best thing is just to watch the Toast messages.  Also you really need to focus on using the debugger. Place a breakpoint on each method and you can see it.  One thing I am sure of is that you cannot directly invoke these methods like `onPause()`. Also keep in mind that in general you don't know when `onDestroy()` will be called.

Comment: Forgive me, but I don't see how this helps me. I have updated the description to clarify what I meant, in short: onDestroy has nothing to do with this.
I need info on what to be prepared for, and what cannot happen. Not everything can be limited in scope to one Activity, and I have no idea, for example, how Activities inside a TabActivity are managed.
Trial and error is out of the question, I almost always get a jump from "everything alive" to "everything but the process destroyed". How to test other cases?
Also, why should I use Toasts? Even system.out seems a better choice.

Comment: I'd also like to add that the documentation stating that, after onPause, "the process hosting the activity may killed by the system at any time without another line of its code being executed" is misleading, individual Activities can be destroyed apart from everything else.
Everything down to the Application object can be destroyed while the process can stay around for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

1. The ActivityManagerService#trimApplications()method remove any unused application processes if the application's current receiver is null, does not have any activity and service.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to activities, they will be only destroyed on on Destroy() until and unless developer manually calls the finish() function,

Fragment life cycle is a completely matched to its parent activity, so when parent activity destroys on on Destroy(), the fragments on Destroy() as well will be called.

Timer Tasks will finish their work and become candidates for garbage collection, once the activity creates them the task runs in its own thread, no relation with activity, even if the activity is destroyed, the task finishes itself....