# Can a background service exist without its main application?

Tags: android, service, background-service

Lets examine the next scenario:

1. I created a new android app, with an application class,  activity and a background service.
2. I have some `static` variable in the application class, lets say it's an int i = 0;
3. I start the `activity`, and start the `service` from the activitie's `onCreate()`, the service gets the `START_STICKY` flag.
4. All that this `service` does is using TimerTask to write the current second to the variable in the application class.
   5.I exit the  activity
5. After a while, Android will kill the service, and the application (lets say that the device is low on resources), and restart the service because of the `START_STICKY` flag.

Now I have to questions:

1. Is the situation when OS kill's the application, but doesn't kill the service?
2. When the service is restarted by the system, will the application restart as well?
   If yes - which context will it have, and if not, how could it be, that there is a service running without his application?

Thanks, sorry about my terrible English...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### **1. Is there a situation when OS kill's the application, but doesn't kill the service?**

**tl;dr:** Yes, this is possible. However, the `Service` must be started in it's own process.

### **Explaination:**

It's important to realize that the Android OS kills *processes* when it's running low on memory, not *individual components*, such as `Activities` or `Services` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576275/1290264)).

Given the above statement, it is clear that a `Service` can exist independent of the `Application` only if they are contained in separate processes. Otherwise, they will be destroyed together when their process is destroyed.

Now consider the case of the `Service` and `Application` existing on separate processes. In Android, processes are destroyed in low memory situations from lowest to highest priority. The priority order is: **Empty < Background < Service < Visible < Foreground** ([see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Lifecycle)). Therefore, it's possible that your `Application` will be destroyed while your `Service` stays alive (e.g. if your Application is in the background) and it's also possible that your `Service` will be destroyed while your Application stays alive (Application is in the foreground).

You can declare any component (Activity, Service, ContentProvider, etc.) of an application to run in it's own process by defining the [`android:process`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) attribute in the components manifest tag.

From the official documentation of [Processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html):

> By default, all components of the same application run in the same process and most applications should not change this. However, [...] the manifest entry for each type of component element — `Activity`, `Service`, `Receiver`, and `Provider` — supports an `android:process` attribute that can specify a process in which that component should run. You can set this attribute so that each component runs in its own process or so that some components share a process while others do not. [...] The `Application` element also supports an android:process attribute, to set a default value that applies to all components.

---

### **2. When the service is restarted by the system, will the application restart as well?**

This is related to the answer in question 1.

If the `Service` exists in the same process as the `Application` then they will both be destroyed and restarted together.

If the `Service` exists in a separate process as the `Application` then they are completely separate processes, and therefore will be destroyed and restarted independent of each other as the Android OS deems appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

> Is the situation when OS will kill the application, but won't kill the
>   service?

yes, there is such situation, generally services will kill after activity, because they demand last resources from the System read [Docs here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startService%28android.content.Intent%29)

> When the service is restarted by the system, will the application
>   restart as well?

am not sure about that, but I think no because service can live without the application reference

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Tomer Mor is not correct.

When your `Application` dies - your `Service`s die too.

Your `Service`s will be created only after your `Application`.
This you can observe yourself by logging their `onCreate()`.