# android.os.TransactionTooLargeException retrieving installed applications

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm recovering all the applications installed on the device and I stumbled upon this error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:499)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivities(ApplicationPackageManager.java:485)
at com.name.package.MyClass$RetrieveApps.doInBackground(MyClass.java:363)
at com.name.package.MyClass$RetrieveApps.doInBackground(MyClass.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.queryIntentActivities(IPackageManager.java:2165)
at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.queryIntentActivitiesAsUser(ApplicationPackageManager.java:493)
... 9 more
```

In doInBackground() method i use this code to retrieve the installed apps.

```
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> mResolveInfo;
    Intent queryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
    mResolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(queryIntent, 0);
    for (ResolveInfo ri : resolveInfos) {
        Class class = new Class();
        class.icon = ri.loadIcon(packageManager);
        class.label = ri.loadLabel(packageManager);
        class.packagename = ri.activityInfo.packageName;
        class.packageclass = ri.activityInfo.name;
        class.componentName = new ComponentName(class.packagename, class.packageclass);
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_RESET_TASK_IF_NEEDED);
        i.setComponent(ai.componentName);
        class.intent = i;
        myArrayList.add(class);
```

The line where the crash occurs is this:

```
mResolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(queryIntent, 0);
```

Reading on stack overflow I understand that this may be caused by the fact that you have many applications installed. The question now is, how can you solve? Is there any solution? If yes, which one? Thanks.

Comment: I got this exact same error by calling `PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES)` on a Nexus 5 in Google's pre-launch report cloud test lab.

Answer (score 3):

I'm looking for the same solution.  Is there any way to do a partial list of installed applications?

I have the same problem in my app.

```
List<PackageInfo> packs = pm.getInstalledPackages(0);
```

If the user has a large number of apps I get this in logcat:

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Package manager has died
    at android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getInstalledPackages(ApplicationPackageManager.java:424)

Caused by: android.os.TransactionTooLargeException
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(Native Method)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub$Proxy.getInstalledPackages(IPackageManager.java:2363)

Update!

I was able to figure out a way.  See this answer that I gave in another post:

[Package manager has died](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774533/package-manager-has-died/23008196#23008196)

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the number of apps that can trigger this issue?