# Are task stack and back stack the same thing in android

Tags: android

I am reading the guide [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html).

And I found this:

> A task is a collection of activities that users interact with when
> performing a certain job. The activities are arranged in a stack (the
> "back stack"), in the order in which each activity is opened.

It seems that the task stack and the back stack are the same concept.

However I wonder if this is true? (I do not why, but I think it may not be simple like this).

Can anybody can explain the relationship for me?

BTW, there can be many tasks(or task stacks) running at the same time(of course only one of them live in the foreground), how about the back stack? Only one or one for each task?

Comment: I think your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975485

Comment: Sounds like it's right. I have not found it when I search "task stack back stack" at stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are right, `task stack` = `back stack`. Note, however, that application may have several tasks.
I find [this](http://www.slideshare.net/RanNachmany/manipulating-android-tasks-and-back-stack) presentation very useful.