# What is the difference between a back stack and a history stack?

Tags: android, back-stack, android-navigation

I was checking on how to start an activity with an empty back stack and encountered the `android:noHistory` attribute. It does what I want but I'm still curious about the term "history stack" being used in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory) of `android:noHistory`. I didn't notice much to any usage of that term throughout the API Guides (e.g. [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)), so are there any differences between back stacks and history stacks or are they simply the same thing?

**Update**

So far there are three terms used in the references:

[History stack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#AndroidManifestActivity_noHistory)

[Back stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html)

[Activity stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist)

This question might start to get nitpicky since it seems that they can all be used interchangeably, but I'm still interested to know the differences if any.

Comment: go through this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975485/whats-the-relationship-between-task-and-back-stack




u will get ..

Comment: @knokZ link provides useful info.. but what about "history stack" and android::noHistory..

Comment: where did you find the term "history stack"? I did not found it here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist Please add a link.

Comment: @Simulant That's the funny part. In that link they describe it as "activity stack" which most likely is the back stack. I added a link to where they mention "history stack".

Answer (score 1):

Well I feel they all are same

From this
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#nohist

```
android:noHistory
A value of "true" means that the activity will not leave a 
historical trace. It will not remain in the activity stack 
for the task, so the user will not be able to return to it.
```

So

**Historical Trace = Activity Stack** (Holding recent Activities) **= History Stack**

and we all know, that [BackStack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) is the one which holds recent activities.

**So, all are pretty much the same thing.**