# understanding fragments back stack and memory

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-fragments

I have an activity with a FrameLayout in which Fragments are replaced during navigation like this:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

// ...
// fragMap is a HashMap<String,Class<?>> mapping fragments classes
Fragment frag;
Class<?> classa = fragMap.get(s);
frag = (Fragment) classa.newInstance();

FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right ,R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.replace(R.id.fragcontainer,  frag);
ft.commit();
```

When pressing back button, the reverse transaction fires and everything seems ok.
When the activity is created, the first fragment A is loaded and memory usage is ~20mb, I then replace A with B and B with C, memory raises to ~40mb. 
When I press back button until fragment A is showed, I would expect memory usage to go back to ~20mb (as it would be with Activities), but it's still stuck at ~40mb. If navigate again through B and C, it doesn't change, still ~40mb.
I really don't understand this behaviour, if fragments were leaking, shouldn't memory raise every time I go from A to B to C?
I also tried to clear backstack with:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
```

but nothing changes. I also checked that `onDestroy` is called on each fragment when navigating back, and it is being called.
Could somebody please help to understand this? Am I using a wrong pattern or what?

Comment: Hey lelloman, did u got any solution?

Comment: @Amrendra hey, I didn't actually get a solution but I didn't have any problem (never got an out of memory exception) so I assumed this is the normal behaviour. I'm just curious to know why it's like this, do you have any actual problem or is it just curiosity?

Comment: @lleloman It is not just curiosity, i have the same problem and never got out of memory exception. Even after activity destroy, memory is not freed by GC

Comment: @Amrendra yeah it sounds like the same situation, my point is that as long as you don't get out of memory exception we can assume that the situation is under control (by the android framework). You could try to increasingly allocate objects and see if the memory that was used by fragments is freed or not. In case the memory you allocate adds up to that used by fragments, you've got a problem

Answer (score 0):

For understanding of backstack please refer to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576275/2582842) from android core engineer it might get you some help.