# Java: Is there a OS/Built-in Timer to kill my App's process?

Tags: java, android

I would like to know, is there an OS/Built-in Timer to call `onDestroy()` method or Kill my app's process?

If yes, how much?

Because i tried to Track my *closed* app from `Settings->Applications->Manage apps`, and the *STOP* Button was *Enabled*, then after Few seconds its gone/disabled.

Comment: onDestroy does not have a timer, it can be called at anytime when your app is in the background by the OS when the OS needs to reclaim resources

Comment: Please read this one. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536988/android-app-out-of-memory-issues-tried-everything-and-still-at-a-loss/7576275#7576275

Comment: To answer the question: Your app can be killed at any moment. You have to develop it with that in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The system will decide when to kill your app's process, usually when it wants to reclaim memory so that other apps can run. There is no guaranteed timing of this or of the `onDestroy` callback.

If you need to destroy your `Activity`, call `finish()` explicitly; if you need to destroy your `Service`, call `stopSelf()` or use `stopService()` from an Activity (or from anything that is/has a Context). If either of those need to be based on a timer, you can use `AlarmManager` to set up a `PendingIntent` and perform the above actions when it fires.

Comment: Well, i think i got it... its about "NO HISTORY" tag in Manifest file. When i set it to TRUE, OS will kill my App's process in background. (while its hide)