# I want to run the code once in an activity

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have an activity that I go back and forth in it. but I want this code to run once inside it even if I switch activity.

```
//get the Current user id(uid)
    userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    Log.i("UID",userId);
    orderDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Orders").child(userId);
    id = orderDatabaseReference.push().getKey();
```

I know the methods onStart, onResume ... but they are also the same

Comment: Most likely you should put this code in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 3):

If you go from one activity to another and come back, all your methods will fire again since the lifecycle starts again, this also happens when you rotate your device, for better understanding about how to persist data, you can see this, if you want to know about Android lifecycle, read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) and [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

You can use `ViewModel` as part of the [Android Architecture Components](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture).

[Guide to app architecture](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide)

[ViewModel](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel) documentation

You can also use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) if you want to persist the data locally.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you want to put this code in `onCreate()` which is run once when the Activity instance is created. It won't run when the user goes to another activity and comes back unless the first activity is destroyed in the mean time. But then most likely you need to refresh your connection to Firebase anyway. As Gaston points out in his answer, you need to learn about the entire Android lifecycle and understand when each event fires in order to decide where to write write your code.

Comment: As one more thing, when @Code-Apprentice points out destroying an activity is when you put `finish()` navigating to other activity or kill the activity in the foreground with your home button

Comment: @GastónSaillén Also, the system may choose to destroy the activity whenever it needs to free resources or in response to a system event such as orientation change. These are more what I had in mind here.

Comment: @GastónSaillén Just to note, early Android documentation stated that individual activities can be killed, but that is not the case.  Only processes are killed if the system needs to free up memory.  See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34971387/4409409 And also see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536988/android-app-out-of-memory-issues-tried-everything-and-still-at-a-loss/7576275#7576275

Comment: @DanielNugent Thanks for the clarification. This is something I was not aware of.