# Android - what happens when the app is forcibly killed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, android-ondestroy

Through [Android's Activities doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html), it is said that the methods [onStop()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop()) and [onDestroy()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onDestroy()) are not guaranteed to be called.

> [...] once the activity is created, onPause() is the last method that's guaranteed to be called before the process can be killed—if the system must recover memory in an emergency, then onStop() and onDestroy() might not be called [...]

I would like to know, when this situation occurs, is the app also killed within the activities or just the activity itself is killed?

Comment: @vamsi-abbineni, could you elaborate more on your answer, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is app process is also get killed and can be recreated.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html 
Please check http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLifeCycle/article.html
Application with only stopped activities and without a service or executing receiver. Android keeps them in a least recent used (LRU) list and if requires terminates the one which was least used.

Comment: Perfect! @hackbod answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7536988/android-app-out-of-memory-issues-tried-everything-and-still-at-a-loss/7576275#7576275 helped me to understand what I needed.

Comment: Thanks @AugustoCarmo for sharing such nice post