# BitmapFactory.Options "inPurgeable" method deprecated

Tags: android

I am new to android programming and I have been doing lots of tutorials all over the internet but I keep bumping into deprecated methods, like for example  when  I call BitmapFactory.Options.inPurgeable, android studio crosses out inPurgeable, giving message that method is deprecated.

Where do I find alternatives to deprecated methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's deprecated because this flag is ignored starting Lollipop. Also use of it can lead to dropped frames. As [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inPurgeable) mentions - use [inBitmap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inBitmap) method instead.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says:

> This field was deprecated in API level 21. **As of
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP, this is ignored**. In
>   Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT and below, if this is set to true, then the
>   resulting bitmap will allocate its pixels such that they can be purged
>   if the system needs to reclaim memory. In that instance, when the
>   pixels need to be accessed again (e.g. the bitmap is drawn,
>   getPixels() is called), they will be automatically re-decoded.

So there should be no need to add this anymore...

... however, [according to Romain Guy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7068403/570168), it still makes sense when `decodeByteArray()` is used:

> This flag is currently completely ignored' is true in certain cases only - in other cases (e.g. when using **decodeByteArray on downloaded data**) then this flag is not ignored and is very, very useful

Comment: Romain Guy answered before change was introduced for Lollipop 21

Comment: 4.3.1 contains purgeable related logic
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-4.3.1_r1:frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp

5.1 nothing here
https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/android-cts-5.1_r20:frameworks/base/core/jni/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.cpp